# JQuery - Multiple Selectors Similar Names in If Statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form with lots of checkboxes - 30+
They are all named a_ something.

eg: a_1, a_2, a_3 etc.

I have an IF statement that is basically saying IF a_1, or a_2 or a_3 is checked do BLAH..
This is working as below :

```
    if (    $('[name=a_1]').prop('checked') 
        ||  $('[name=a_2]').prop('checked') 
        ||  $('[name=a_3]').prop('checked')
        ||  $('[name=a_4]').prop('checked') 
        ||  $('[name=a_5]').prop('checked') )
```

However as there are 30+ possible checkboxes this is getting to be a long bit of code. If there any way to do this and reference any 'a_' checkbox. ?

So if any 'a_' checkbox is ticked do BLAH. ?

I though this would work, but it only worked on the first checkbox.

```
if ( $('[name=^a_]').prop('checked') )
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: I'm wondering what you're doing inside that one if statement. I think you may want to post your full code at codereview.stackexchange.com so others can take a look and give helpful suggestions/examples.

Comment: The IF statement is basically just warning the user they have selected one of the checkboxes. If any checkbox is selected an alert is shown.

It's not actually needed, just on of the users thought it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
if ($('[name^="a_"]').is(':checked')) {
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YXT4f/)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me ! If I revert my code back and select a checkbox I then get an alert showing a checkbox has been selected.  When I tried this nothing happened. My IF statement works, but seems a bit messy.